# ASP.NET Core MVC - Invalid Operation Exception There is no viewdata of type Ienumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ienumerable, cascadingdropdown, viewdata

I am trying to cascade State Names according to the Country name selected in the Country drop down. 
I have written the JS for post method for selected Country. But when i added the state dropdown list in view and debug it. I get the error - There is no Viewdata of type Ienumerable of key StateName1.

NewRequestView Model

```
public class NewRequestView 
{    
    public string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }        
}
```

Country Model

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public IActionResult NewRequest()
    {
        var model = new NewRequestView { };                      
        model.Countries = iMapper.Map<IEnumerable<Country>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(GetCountries());            
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-10 multiSelectCheckboxDiv" id="multiSelectCheckboxDiv">
                                    <span class="col1 contrlLabel" style=" font-family:calibri;color:gray;font-size:15px">Clients<span style="font-weight:800;color:red;">*</span>:</span>
                                    @Html.DropDownList("CountryName", Model.Countries ,"Select Country",new { @class = "form-control"})
                                    <div class="input-validation-errorText col-md-6" style="display:none;">
                                        Please select Country.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-10 multiSelectCheckboxDiv" id="multiSelectCheckboxDiv">
                                    <span class="col1 contrlLabel" style=" font-family:calibri;color:gray;font-size:15px">Clients<span style="font-weight:800;color:red;">*</span>:</span>
                                    @Html.DropDownList("StateName1", Model.State, "Select State", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    <div class="input-validation-errorText col-md-6" style="display:none;">
                                        Please select state.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I Used AutoMapper to map the Country Names.

Mapper

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Client, SelectListItem>()
             .ForMember(x => x.Text, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.CountryName))
             .ForMember(x => x.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => o.CountryName));

        });
        return config.CreateMapper();
```

From Selected Country I am firing JS to get all the state Names. But before i select itself i am getting the error

> InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'StateName1'.

Let me know what is the error i am doing here

Comment: I'm confused, why are you assigning to the mapper `Model.Clients`? It's not even in your model.

Comment: @JerdineSabio sorry that was a type.. its Model.Countries.. i have updated my question

Comment: Ok, found the cause of the error.

Comment: Where does your state records come from btw?

Comment: When i select a particular country from the country drop down, the value of country is passed on to a method through ajax and gets the list of state records to populate in another drop down

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio is correct. The error is that `Model.State` is null in view,do you still have any problem?

Comment: @XingZou  i was able to resolve using Jerdine's solution. But i am stuck up in another issue.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799823/0x800a01b6-javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method?noredirect=1#comment107571032_60799823

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Invalid Operation Exception There is no viewdata of type Ienumerable

This is caused by a null list being supplied to `Html.DropdownList()` in your view.

Looking at your controller action, you don't have anything that gives `model.State` value.

```
public IActionResult NewRequest()
{
   var model = new NewRequestView { };                      
   model.Countries = iMapper.Map<IEnumerable<Country>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>(GetCountries());

   // you need something like this
   model.State = new List<SelectListItem>(){
      new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Test", Value = "Test" }
   };

   return View(model);
}
```

---

Another option is, since the State Records will come from an ajax event once a Country is selected, you could actually just leave model.State blank and don't use `Html.Dropdown()`.

You can do this;
The manually created select field will still be recognized as part of the model when you submit the form.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-10 multiSelectCheckboxDiv" id="multiSelectCheckboxDiv">
      <span class="col1 contrlLabel" style=" font-family:calibri;color:gray;font-size:15px">Clients<span style="font-weight:800;color:red;">*</span>:</span>

      <select id="StateName1" name="Model.State" class="form-control">
         <option>Select State</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-validation-errorText col-md-6" style="display:none;">
         Please select state.
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no if i use this i get the below error 
"Try specifiying the type arguments explicitly". Cannot create an instanc eof an abstract class or interface Ienumerable<SelectListItem>

I used this 

model.State= new IEnumerable<SelectListItem>(){
                new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Test", Value = "Test" }
            };

Comment: @GladstoneJaffrey Updated answer, I changed it to List.

Comment: @GladstoneJaffrey I added another option, you could leave model.State empty, just change your view to not use Html.Dropdown for model.State because you have to supply a list to it. Declare a manual select field instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call to get the States by passing the Country ID to your method and return the StateList in JSON.

Check [Cascaded Dropdown Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/) for a step-by-step walkthrough.